# change FirestoreRecyclerAdapter clicked item color

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use FirestoreRecyclerAdapter in which i want change selected item color. because in firestoreAdapter it comes  to  onBindViewHolder() only item data change.for single item replace it ,but i want to change all item text color to which except selected item.

how can i do ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse your logic then. Declare a `list` that keeps the clicked item (store the index, id or whatever you prefer), then in your `onBindViewHolder()`, do nothing if the clicked item is in that `list`, else change whatever you want.

Of course, you must update this `list` if you allow insertion/removal/change in your list.

**EDIT**

To answer your questions in your comments, first you must design the logic to change the color accordingly in `onBindViewHolder()`. Then, set `onClickListener` to the responding view. Lastly, to refresh your displaying list, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or similar methods.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    // declaration and setup here

    final index = position;

    // Define the logic to change the color if clicked item is/not in the list
    if (yourClickedItemList.contain(position)) {
        // Change what you want
    }
    else {
        // Change what you want if the item is not in the list
    }

    // Then set the click listener
    viewHolder.yourItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!yourClickedItemList.contain(index)) {
                yourClickedItemList.add(index);
            }
            else {
                // the list already contain that item
                // do whatever you want here, like toggle off selection and remove from the list
            }

            // call to refresh your view
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // or use notifyItemChanged() etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i can chage item color and background only in onBindViewHolder(). e.g : for first time i want 0 index item color change and after that if i click another item then i want to change clicked index item color and 0th idex color to normal.

Comment: and every time data change my whole list never get refreshed. only that clicked item replace